# Eclipse Remote Search Cancelled

Tags: eclipse

I am very new to Eclipse. I am trying to do a basic remote search in my C:/SomeFolder drive using CTRL+H, however whenever I perform the search, the search gets cancelled automatically after 2 seconds or so. Do you know why this is happening and how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I had "Search archive files" selected. Once I unchecked it, everything worked fine.